# Querying subdocument inside a subdocument of a collection in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have the collection named companies as below.

I want to query the url corresponding to C1S1category1 . I do not know which companyName it belongs and which catergories it belongs to.

Please can you let me know what query I need to use in Mongoshell to query the document having catergoryname as C1S1category1

```
{"companyName": "C1",
"url": "www.com1",
"categories" : [
        {"SlNo" : 1,
        "url" : "www.com1",
        "subcategories" : [
            {
            "CatergoryName":"C1S1category1",
            "Url" : "www.com3"
            },
            {
            "CatergoryName":"C1S1category2",
            "Url" : "www.com3"
            }
            ]
         },
       {
       "SlNo" : 2,
        "url" : "www.com1",
        "subcategories" : [
            {
            "CatergoryName":"C1S2category1",
            "Url" : "www.com3"
            },
            {
            "CatergoryName":"C1S2category2",
            "Url" : "www.com3"
            }
            ]
        }   
    ]
},
{"companyName": "C2",
"url": "www.com21",
"categories" : [
        {"SlNo" : 1,
        "url" : "www.com22",
        "subcategories" : [
            {
            "CatergoryName":"C2S1category1",
            "Url" : "www.com23"
            },
            {
            "CatergoryName":"C2S1category2",
            "Url" : "www.com23"
            }
            ]
         },
       {
       "SlNo" : 2,
        "url" : "www.com1",
        "subcategories" : [
            {
            "CatergoryName":"C2S2category1",
            "Url" : "www.com23"
            },
            {
            "CatergoryName":"C2S2category2",
            "Url" : "www.com23"
            }
            ]
        }   
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch) to get required output as following:

```
db.collection.find({
    "categories": {
    $elemMatch: {
        subcategories: {
            $elemMatch: {
                CatergoryName: "C1S1category1"
            }
        }
    }
    }
},{"categories.$":1,"companyName":1,"url":1}).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks Vishwas. The above query returns complete document. Is it possible to return the sub documents that only get matched.

Comment: @Sham332 use [$ project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) like this `find({your query criteria},{"categories.$":1}`

Comment: @Sham332 please see edited answer. If you want only sub document then use `{"categories.$":1}` only.